# Calculator that accepts multiple inputs like +, -, and a number squared. Pulling info from text file

Tags: c++

I have this assignment:

> Write an even better calculator program calc3.cpp that can understand squared numbers. We are going to use a simplified notation X^ to mean X2. For example, 10^ + 7 - 51^ should mean 10^2 + 7 − 51^2.

*Imagine you have a file formula.txt with the summation formula like:*

```
    5^; = 25
    1000 + 6^ - 5^ + 1;  = 1012
```

At first I used switch/case statements, which didn't exactly work, and was too hard for me to understand. I'm using if statements now. I'm not sure what's wrong with my if statements, I think there's more I need to add in each of the if statements inside the +, and - statements, but I don't know what.

Thank you so much!

```
cin >> sum;                      
sum == rightNum;

while (cin >> op) { 
    if(op == '^') {
        sum += rightNum * rightNum;
        cin >> op;
        }

    if(op == '+') {
        cin >> rightNum;
        cin >> op;
            if(op == '^') {
            sum += rightNum * rightNum;
            }
            else {
            sum += rightNum;
            }
    }


    if(op == '-') {
        cin >> rightNum;
        cin >> op;
            if(op == '^') {
            sum -= rightNum * rightNum;
            }
            else {
            sum -= rightNum;
            }
    }


    if(op == ';') {
        cout << sum << endl;
        cin >> sum;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Start from the worked example in K & R. Define a new type of *term* which can include the suffixed `^` and go from there. It will have the highest *precedence* of all the operators.

Comment: `sum == rightNum;` is not an assignment. Your compiler should have warned you about this.

Comment: whoops, okay I took that out, because when I made it sum = rightNum it broke the code even more

Comment: Fire up a debugger and step through the code, watching the values inside the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have built gathering and executing the next operation into the code that handles the previous operation you have built a program that cannot scale effectively. Instead loop around getting an operator and getting the right operand and then, if you can ignore operator precedence, execute the operation on the previous result and operand. If you have to take operator precedence into account, ignore this answer and start looking into priority queues and trees.

Something like

```
cin >> result; // get first operand. If there is no operator, this is the answer
while (true) // loop forever!
{
    cin >> op;
    if (op == ';')
    {
        print result and exit loop.
    }
    cin >> operand;
    switch(op)
    {
        case '+':
            result += operand;
            break;
        case '-':
            result -= operand;
            break;

        other operations go here
    }
}
```

Now that we have a basic framework that can handle any number of operations we can approach handling the ^. It's best here if you do not treat it as an operation because it's not being used as one. It's more of a modifier.

If the syntax looked like 10 ^ 2, you'd have an operator, but 10^ has no right hand operand, and this screws up the left-operand, operator, right-operand structure of the rest of the code.

So how do we do this? Any time you read a number from the user, peek at the next character. If it is ^, multiply the number read by itself.

Replace `T` with whatever type is required.

```
T readnumber()
{
    T val;
    cin >> val;
    if (cin.peek() == '^')
    { // found ^
        val *= val; // square the value
        cin.ignore() // remove the ^ so no one else trips over it
    }
    return val;
}
```

Note that the above completely ignores input validation and will hilariously mishandle bad input. Users are notoriously stupid as well as bad typists. Do not trust the users to give the program good input. In general, do not trust the users at all.

Replacing `cin >>` with `readnumber` we get something like

```
result = readnumber(); 
while (true) 
{
    cin >> op;
    if (op == ';)
    {
        print result and exit loop.
    }
    operand = readnumber();
    switch(op)
    {
        case '+':
            result += operand;
            break;
        case '-':
            result -= operand;
            break;

        other operations go here
    }
}
```

Side note: consider replacing `cin` with a generic `std::istream` so that these functions can be used with any type of stream.

Suggestion based on comments:

```
int calculate(istream & in)
{
    result = readnumber(in); 
    while (true) 
    {
        in >> op;
        if (op == ';)
        {
            break;
        }
        operand = readnumber(in);
        switch(op)
        {
            case '+':
                result += operand;
                break;
            case '-':
                result -= operand;
                break;

            other operations go here
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`calculate` then sits inside a loop and repeatedly called until you've run out of inputs.

Bonus suggestion: Use `std::getline` to get statements delimited by ';'

```
string statement;
while (getline(in, statement, ';'))
{
    calculate(stringstream(statement)); 
}
```

`getline` removes the ';' so it can't be used to exit the loop in `calculate` but this actually makes things a bit easier: you can exit on the `stringstream` being empty or in a fail state,

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again. I understand what I did wrong, but how do I   print result and exit loop for the ';' statement? I did cout << result << endl; then cin >> result, but this doesn't seem to be working properly.

Comment: `cout << result << endl;` is correct, but the next thing you want to do is `break;`. Alternately you can `break` and print the result outside the loop.

Comment: when I `break` the code only runs once and prints the one line. Like 5 + 5;  4^ -2, only prints the 10

Comment: I want it to go to print the result, then reset the result and go back and do it again. :/

Comment: You need another loop around the code you have. The inner loop processes one ';' delimited statement. The outer loop would have to keep keep running the inner loop until some terminating condition is met, like no more lines of input. Probably best if you take the code that processes a statement and turn it into a function and keep calling that function until out of statements..